# another stripslashes problem

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, mysql-real-escape-string, stripslashes

I didnt find a real solution for this.
As many others now I use a jquery wysiwyg editor and save the output in mysql. The problem occurs when I load back into editor and save it again. The backslash and the " marks increasing every time when I press submit.
Off course before write to DB I do a `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

I use the strpslashes recursively but it doesnt work.

```
function decodeEscapedString($value) {
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

     $value = is_array($value) ?
       array_map(array('self', 'decodeEscapedString'), $value) :
       stripslashes($value);

     return $value;

  } else
     return stripslashes($value);
}
```

Could somebody have an idea?
thx

Comment: At least there will be no magic quotes in PHP 5.4

Comment: If you've got control of the server, why not just disable magic quotes in the first place?  It makes everything a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have a slight logic error as well as a possible reference error where you have `'self'` in the `array_map()`.

Assuming this is a class method, try something like this

```
public function filter($value)
{
    return get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? $this->clean($value) : $value;
}

protected function clean($value)
{
    return is_array($value) ? array_map(array($this, 'clean'), $value) : stripslashes($value);
}
```

You then just call the `filter()` method, eg

```
$value = $obj->filter($_POST['something']);
```

Adapted from http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2008/10/zend-framework-forms-and-magic_quotes_gpc/